# Windows Server 2008 start menu showing unexpected items in right click menu

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

I have 3 Windows Server 2008 Standard virtual servers on Hyper-V. On 2 of them when I right click the Start menu I get the standard selections: Open, Explore, etc. but on the other I get the same menu you get when you right click the task bar: Toolbars, Task Manager, etc. I cannot figure out how this was changed or how to return it to normal.

Comment: Are right clicks behaving otherwise correctly on the odd machine?

Comment: Yes, other right clicks work as expected.

Comment: check if the task bar is locked or not

Comment: Does this problem persist outside of the Hyper-V manager? For example, if you try to access the same server via RDP do you get the same results? Could be problem with video in Hyper-V.

Comment: Are they all at the same service pack level and release number?

Comment: I ran out of time and punted and just rebuilt the machines which were part of a dev environment.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a long shot but have you tried re-registering your `shell.dll`?

`regsvr32 /i shell32.dll`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clean it up, you can use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)

Ideally, you would want to know where it came from... (the properties might contain details from where it originated from).